# edited: accessing a method in a running c++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11

I need to make a statistical printout of a socket program.

I am using method Listen(uint32_t port) in c++ thread to listen to clients on the specified port (more than one) and send/receive client's transactions to/from a server.

Now i need to write a log file of how many packet received/sent by this method.
my implementation is shown in the skeleton below:

```
hub.cpp


//set up necessary header
#include <iostream>
....
#include <vector>

//global variables
std::map<uint32_t,long> * received_pk;

std::map<uint32_t,long> * sent_pk;

void Listen(uint32_t port ); // method

int main (int argc, char **argv){

//set up client ports
vector<uint32_t> client_ports;
client_ports.push_back(50002);
client_ports.push_back(50003);

//initialize variables

received_pk = new std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t>();

sent_pk = new std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t>();

  for(uint32_t i=0;i<client_ports.size();i++){
    received_pk->insert(std::pair<uint32_t,uint32_t>(client_ports.at(i),0) );
    sent_pk->insert(std::pair<uint32_t,uint32_t>(client_ports.at(i),0) );
  }
//set up thread
vector<thread*> threads;
for(uint32_t i=0;i<client_ports.size();i++){
  cout << "Create Listener in port " << client_ports.at(i) << endl;
  threads.push_back(new thread(Listen,client_ports.at(i)));
  }
//Wait for the threads to finish
  for(uint32_t i=0;i<client_ports.size();i++){
    threads.at(i)->join();
  }
}
void Listen(uint32_t port){
 ...
set up struct sockaddr_in client, host;
listen on port: port
...
  while(1){
    receive packet from client;
    received_pk->at(port)++;
    check packet type
    if(packet==status packet){
      update the packet id number
    }
    if (packet==transaction){
      send packet to Server
      receive reply
      send reply back to client
      sent_pk->at(port)++;
    }

  }

}
```

Now i need to access received_pk and sent_pk while hub.cpp is still running (probably in the while loop)

I thought of two options:

1. Access  received_pk and sent_pk from an external program: like define a method that can get the packet information while the thread is till running

**problem: I don't know if i can access a variable/method while program is executing .**

2. or print received_pk and sent_pk to a log file every 5 seconds.

**problem: I don't know if it makes sense to have a timer in the multiple thread.**

Please any advice will be appreciated.

Kehinde

Comment: Asking two completely orthogonal questions in a single one doesn't fit the required Stack Overflow format well.

Comment: If I understand the first question correctly, by "program" you mean "process", then no that's not possible.

Comment: it's always a good idea to include code snippets in your question; it's clearer for anyone trying to answer and it might even help you understand what the problem is...

Comment: @user3528438 That's not completely true, a program that was compiled for debugging can well be accessed (attached) while it's running.

Comment: @Kehinde: Format your code with `\`code\``. The `< >` after map was invisible because it looked like bad HTML

Comment: @user3528438 i edited the comment

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly, the easiest solution is to put the data in *shared memory*. The `map x` is a bit suspect - did you mean `std::map<Key, Value>`? That doesn't fit well in shared memory. Instead, use simple arrays. There are just 64K ports, and `sizeof(long long[65536])` isn't excessive.

Comment: Hi @MSalter, thanks for the answer, I modified the post by adding the skeleton of my code. Can you please check again Thanks

Comment: Yeah - that map won't fit in shared memory. Also, way too many `new` calls. (Also not enough `delete` but that is a separate problem)

Comment: i did not include the delete in the skeleton. I deleted then in the main code. Can you explain a bit more the shared memory